# Why is "Script" the child of "Body"?

Tags: javascript, html

First of all I am very bad at HTML/CSS/Javascript, I am just trying to pass my exams. I have the following piece of code:

```
<script>
    window.onload=function() {
    var c = document.body.childNodes;
    var txt = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    txt = txt + c[i].nodeName + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt;
    alert(document.getElementById("demo").childNodes[0].nodeName);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body><!-- Comm -->
    <p>PPPP</p>
    <div>DIVV</div>
    <p>IMGGG</p><br>
    <img src="someimg.jpg" alt="!!!">
    <p id="demo"><strong>document.body.childNodes:</strong><br>
    </p>
    </body>
```

My html page looks now like this:

```
PPPP

DIVV
IMGGG


!!!
document.body.childNodes:
#comment
#text
P
#text
DIV
#text
P
BR
#text
IMG
#text
P
#text
#comment
#text
SCRIPT
#text
```

Where do the last two lines ("SCRIPT" and "#text") come from ?

Comment: Looks like a script is inserted at the end of your body. Either by the tool you are using to run it, or by the browser/a browser extension. Can't you see any scripts when inspecting the source using the developer tools of your browser?

Comment: You are right, thank you. But still annoys me that I do not know where it comes from.

Comment: I have no way of knowing that either. You can see what the script contains to see that gives you a hint. Otherwise you can disable each browser extension/plugin, until it goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Please see a complete listing of both source and output. In your sample, the last **5** tags appear to have a problem.

### Source

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);
function onLoaded(evt)
{
    var i, txt='', c = Array.from(document.body.childNodes), tgt=document.getElementById("demo");
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) 
    {
        txt = c[i].nodeName + "<br>";
        tgt.innerHTML += txt;
    }
    alert(document.getElementById("demo").childNodes[0].nodeName);
}
</script>
</head>
<body><!-- Comm -->
    <p>PPPP</p>
    <div>DIVV</div>
    <p>IMGGG</p><br>
    <img src="someimg.jpg" alt="!!!">
    <p id="demo"><strong>document.body.childNodes:</strong><br>
    </p></body>
</html>
```

### Output

```
PPPP

DIVV
IMGGG


!!!
document.body.childNodes:
#comment
#text
P
#text
DIV
#text
P
BR
#text
IMG
#text
P
#text
```

### Detail

- IMG - is the image
- #text - is the whitespace between IMG and P
- P - is the `<p id='demo'>`
- #text - is the whitespace inserted by the browser between `</p>` and `</body>`